# Qlik IntervalMatch to SQL

Tags: sql, join, amazon-redshift, intervals, qliksense

I have an example of code from Qlik documentation [doc](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/May2023/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/ScriptPrefixes/IntervalMatch.htm):

```
EventLog:

LOAD * Inline [

Time, Event, Comment
00:00, 0, Start of shift 1
01:18, 1, Line stop
02:23, 2, Line restart 50%
04:15, 3, Line speed 100%
08:00, 4, Start of shift 2
11:43, 5, End of production
];


OrderLog:
LOAD * INLINE [
Start, End, Order
01:00, 03:35, A
02:30, 07:58, B
03:04, 10:27, C
07:23, 11:43, D
];

//Link the field Time to the time intervals defined by the fields Start and End.

Inner Join IntervalMatch ( Time )
 
LOAD Start, End
Resident OrderLog;
```

As you can see there are two tables `EventLog` and `OrderLog`. The result of this operation is

| Time | Start | End | Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00:00 | - | - | - |
| 01:18 | 01:00 | 03:35 | A |
| 02:23 | 01:00 | 03:35 | A |
| 04:15 | 02:30 | 07:58 | B |
| 04:15 | 03:04 | 10:27 | C |
| 08:00 | 03:04 | 10:27 | C |
| 08:00 | 07:23 | 11:43 | D |
| 11:43 | 07:23 | 11:43 | D |

Now I have such a thing `Some_table1` has many column and specific `col1` column. There is `Some_table2` that has for example `start_` and `end_` columns. From this code:

```
Some_table1: //has col1 column
//Loads etc.

INTERVAL_MATCH:
IntervalMatch (col1)
LOAD DISTINCT
     start_
    ,end_
RESIDENT Some_table2;
```

how can I achieve it in Amazon SQL (based on postgresql)? Is there any built-in function or do I have to use some kind of a JOIN?